How to mark all controls inside formGroup as untouched?
I have a FormGroup which has three controls inside. When I add values of three controls in list, by button click, then all form controls display 'red line' around them due to null/empty value. I want to get rid of this behavior (no redline). I can call the setError(null) method on the individual control which removes the red line around single control, but I want to do this directly on the FormGroup. markAsPristine() and markAsUntouched() don't work either. Calling setError(null) on FormGroup doesn't work either.

Your question is unclear. How are you adding values by "button click"? If you added values, how do the controls end up being empty? How is the "red line" implemented? Ideally, can you set up a minimal reproduction in StackBlitz?

Please reproduce the error in StackBlitz as mentioned by JSONDerulo. Aside, I don't see <FormGroup>.markAsUntouched() is not working in this demo.
